# How to force Nuxt 2 middleware runs at least once on the client

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

on static site generation mode in Nuxt 2, global middleware (defined in nuxt.config) runs only on the server-side on the first page load. and will run on the client-side for further page navigations.

To get around this issue, I put my code inside of a Nuxt plugin:

```
plugins: [
  { src: '~/plugins/initializer.js', mode: 'client' }
   // other plugins
]
```

but this is not suitable for some scenarios, because plugins run after middleware.

I need to force a Middleware to run at least once on the client-side even dur
the first page load.